# html 5 video to automatically open in fullscreen mode when user enter the current webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ios

1. first，I  create a webpage,and in this page has a button  linked to
   the html5 video player page(this is another page)
2. and then, I want to achieve that when click the button, the next
   page(html5 video player page)can automatic full screen.

   ## **I want it to run in IPhone**

I try it use the code

```
window.load=function(){
 myVideo=document.getElementById('video')[0];
 if(!myVideo.webkitDisplayingFullscreen){
    goFullscreen();
 }
 function goFullScreen(){ myVideo.webkitEnterFullscreen();}
}
```

> and the chrome said:
>   Uncaught InvalidStateError:Failed to execute'webkitEnterFullscreen'
>   on 'HTMLVideoElement': This element may only enter fullscreen mode in
>   response to a user gesture

so is there some other solutions to  get the fullscreen mode automatically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a video as background of your page like my example, check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/N4Lbp/4/

fullscreen: https://jsfiddle.net/N4Lbp/4/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="http://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png" id="video_bg">
<source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_720p_stereo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#video_bg {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: -100;
    background: url(http://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```